# Do you say "half boarding school"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

I know that "**boarding school**" means students live in school and don't go home during the school year. They might go home on weekends.

In Vietnam, we have 3 types of school.

-**Type 1**: you get to school at 7am and then go home at 11 am to have lunch at home. So, the students are at home from noon to the next morning. Sometimes, maybe 1 or 2 days a week, if the school requires them to get to school to do some activities in the afternoon, then they get back to school after lunch or after taking a noon nap. And then they go back home at 3 or 4pm. So, they go **home twice** in a day (**note**: this only happens a few days a week, not every day).

-**Type 2**: you get to school at 7am and have lunch at school (the school will provide lunch or you have to pack lunch to school). After lunch, you study from 1pm to 3pm or 4pm, then you go home. If I translate this type of school from my mother tongue to English, it will be "**half-boarding school**"

-**Type 3**: you stay in school during the school year. You might visit home during weekends. So, this is definitely boarding school.

**Do you have a word for "type 2" school? maybe half-boarding school?**

**Also, Do you have a word for "type 1" school?**

Comment: Schools of type 1 are very rare or non-existent in the UK. Even if they were not, they, and type 2 would be called 'day schools'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type 2 is the normal type of school in English-speaking countries. Children don't go home for lunch (although I think they sometimes did in the days when most married women stayed at home).

It's only a boarding school if the pupils sleep there. Some boarding schools allow children who live not too far away to be *weekly boarders* - they sleep at school during the week and go home at weekends.

Comment: Many UK schools [allow pupils to go home for lunch](https://www.ranelagh.newham.sch.uk/page/?title=School+Lunch+Menu&pid=62), and [some schools](https://headlandsschool.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/Edwards-A-Lunchtime-Letter-Year-9-11.pdf) only allow students who have not have bad marks for behaviour to do so.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - OK. I had assumed that it didn't happen these days, since most mothers go out to work.

Comment: Type 2 is normal in the US, also; when I was a child, kindergarten was often, but not always, type 1 (with a second session for other students in the afternoon). Today, it appears that even kindergarten has gone type 2 nearly universally. Type 1, where it still exists, might be called 'Half-day sessions'; type 2 is called a 'day school' when it is necessary to distinguish from a type 3 'boarding school' or 'residential school'.

Answer (score 0):

Type 2: **Extended Day School**

This would be the closest equivalent to your idea of a "half-boarding school." It's not a commonly used term, but it conveys the meaning well.
Some other ways to describe this type of school:
"School with lunch program" or
"Full-day school" (though this can sometimes be ambiguous)